# Download attachments with same name without overwriting

Tags: vba, outlook

Below is the script to download an attachment from mails in Outlook.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim dateFormat

    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    sSaveFolder = "c:\My\temp\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

It downloads and stores in the path which is mentioned in my code only when attachment has different name.

For example, I received mail with attachment as 'List.csv'. With same name I received mail around 10 times.

But only one file (most recent one) got saved in the path.

---

Final code which works for me.

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim dt30daysAgo As Date

    dt30daysAgo = DateAdd("d", -30, Now)
    saveFolder = "c:\My\temp"

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If itm.ReceivedTime > dt30daysAgo Then
            If objAtt.FileName <> "list.csv" Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.FileName
            Else
                objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & itm.Subject & objAtt.FileName
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if these attachments have the same name, i would guess they are being overwritten, try adding something like a counter on the end of the filename. Or maybe the delivery date of the email

Comment: So check to see if the file exists before saving, and if it does then alter the filename of the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just overwritting any existing file having the same name.

A very simple solution is to append the current date/time to the file name prior to save it.

To download attachments from the last 30 days only, add a check at the beginning of the procedure to compare the Mail's `ReceivedTime` with the date 30 days ago, and exit the procedure if received time is lower.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim dt30daysAgo As Date

    dt30daysAgo = DateAdd("d", 30, Now)

    If MItem.ReceivedTime < dt30daysAgo Then Exit Sub

    sSaveFolder = "c:\My\temp\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD_hh-nn-ss") & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

But the check on `ReceivedTime` is not well placed, you should ideally do this this on the calling procedure.

Comment: Thanks .It worked. I append subject of the mail to it.But How to download attachments from the last 30 days only.

Comment: @Azarudeen You mean the attachements for only the emails that have been sent over the last 30 days ?

Comment: Yes, I do this task once in a month. So I don't want attachments which already downloaded in the last month.

Comment: @Azarudeen check my adapted answer

Comment: Hi Thomas, I made some changes to code as suggested by you. Still ended in error.Please see my updated question.